# share video with react-native-fbsk

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to post a video to Facebook with the react-native-fbsdk

so far I managed to post a image to Facebook with this code!

```
        const sharePhotoContent = {
            contentType: 'photo',
            photos: [
                {
                    imageUrl: uri,
                    userGenerated: false,
                }
            ]
        };
        this.setState({ sharePhotoContent: sharePhotoContent, })
    })
```

I tried to post a video in many ways but I could not find the right way to do it?

// this one doesn't work!!

```
 this.refs.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
        const shareVideoContent = {
            contentType: 'video',
            localUrl: image,
        };
        this.setState({ shareVideoContent: shareVideoContent, })
    })
```

is there someone who already did this?

would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you check [this page](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/models/FBShareVideoContent.js) you can find the video share content structure.

```
export type ShareVideoContent = {
  // The type of content to be shared is photo.
  contentType: 'video',

  // Common parameters for share content;
  commonParameters?: ShareContentCommonParameters,

  // URL for the content being shared.
  contentUrl?: string,

  // Video to be shared.
  video: ShareVideo,

  //  Description of the video.
  contentDescription?: string,

  // Title of the video.
  contentTitle?: string,

  // The photo that represents the video.
  previewPhoto?: SharePhoto,
};

export type ShareVideo = {
  // The URL to the video. Must point to the location of the video on disk.
  localUrl: string,
};
```

Comment: Not directly. I can try to help if you are having any problems. Just update your code with the current version so I can check it out better.